# Insert Cyrillic strings with stored procedure by parameter SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following `insert` statement in a stored procedure:

```
INSERT INTO Persons (ID, Name, LocationID) 
VALUES (@MaxId, @Name, @LocationID)
```

It works fine until I get a name with Cyrillic characters (i.e дом), which added a record with name = ???

I know I can use something like that:

```
INSERT INTO Assembly 
VALUES(N'Македонски парлиамент број 1', '', '');
```

But how can I use it with SQL parameters?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show how the `@Name` parameter is initialized?

Comment: You need to define @Name as nvarchar.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you should check the followings:

1. Is `@Name` variable with `NVARCHAR` type? If it is a `VARCHAR` type it cannot store properly your Cyrillic values.
2. If you are setting the `@Name` value by yourself, check if there is `N` before the string value (as in your example)

Comment: I can't add the value by myself because I'm sending it by code. Also, it's nvarchar field

Comment: The problem was the initialization as you mentioned. It was varchar.

Thanks guys!:)